# Tensorflow runtime failed to load on Windows 7

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have searched and tried the solutions I found including installation of numpy and scipy, and I keep getting this same error.

I'd appreciate any help I could get on this.

I can see that a DLL failed to load but I can't tell which DLL it's looking for.

Here is the Traceback info:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sif\foto2vam\foto2vam.py", line 93, in <module>
    main( args )
  File "C:\Users\Sif\foto2vam\foto2vam.py", line 67, in main
    predictor.main(params)
  File "C:\Users\Sif\foto2vam\Tools\MakePrediction.py", line 20, in main
    from keras.models import load_model
  File "C:\Users\Sif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\ke
ras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Users\Sif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\ke
ras\utils\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import conv_utils
  File "C:\Users\Sif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\ke
ras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .. import backend as K
  File "C:\Users\Sif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\ke
ras\backend\__init__.py", line 84, in <module>
    from .tensorflow_backend import *
  File "C:\Users\Sif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\ke
ras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\Sif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\te
nsorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-im
port
  File "C:\Users\Sif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\te
nsorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Sif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\te
nsorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\te
nsorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Sif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\te
nsorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Sif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\te
nsorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\Sif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init
__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795
```

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.